# List of items with custom views/layouts

Tags: android, list, listview, data-binding, scroll

I need a way to create a vertically scroll-able list. The list should then contain a bunch of rows, where each row should have an image button, an image , three `TextViews` and two images.
Like this:

```
Row1: ImgBtn | TextView | TextView | TextView | Image | Image 

Row2: ImgBtn | TextView | TextView | TextView | Image | Image 

Row3: ImgBtn | TextView | TextView | TextView | Image | Image
```

..and so on..

I also need to "bind" the views to some values.. since the value of the `TextViews` and the images and so on should be "fetched" from a database.

**Question:**

whats the best approach and is there any place where I can read some more about this?.. Im not really sure of what to google, so thats one of the reasons for why Im asking and not googeling it myself :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this Guide I wrote on how to create a custom `ListView`:

[Custom ListView](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=495)

Basiclly you need to create a `CustomArrayAdapter`, reed the guide to get an idea of how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a component. A component is a custom object different of what Android offers you directly. More info here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html

Once you make your custom component, you just need to instantiate your custom item on getView()

Answer (score 0):

You should extend `BaseAdapter` and define your own adapter that the `ListView` will use.
Here are some articles that shows how to do it:
http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429
http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/01/07/building-a-custom-fancy-listview-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to create a custom listview, you should use extend 'arrayAdapter'. Maybe this tutorial will help you: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom layout with what you want and use that instead of **android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1** and use **android.layout.yourxml**,search in google how you can do this  and also you can search what you want to do for customizing android listview with adapter

Answer (score 0):

Well you don't need a custom view you just need to make a layout to be your row_layout or any other name to be something like this like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_lang" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_lang" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_lang" />
```

then inflate it in the Adapter then assign data to that view for example from your database. What you need in steps is to:

- Make a Layout
- Listview
- Adapter(Assigns data to the listView row by row with you layout)
  I was learning about lists myself these past weeks it will seem lengthy at first 
  but will become very easy when you get the process, so here are some links that might help you:
- [Android offical website](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html)
- [Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)